# Deploying Windows Application(C#) using visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, windows, setup-deployment

I am stuck while deploying my windows application (C#) in Visual Studio 2008. I am using setup wizard project to create the msi/exe file. This setup files I need to copy to the UAT server, run the setup and then use the application.
The main issue here is, I have created this application on my local machine and then installing it on UAT by taking remote of UAT server. This works properly. But when my colleague is running same application from his local machine by taking remote of UAT server, the application crashes.
Since the application working with my login, there seems to be no problem with the code.We are using our own windows login credentials for taking remote of UAT server.

Below is the error screenshot: 
[image]

Please suggest what can be the possible reasons for the same application crashing with other user's id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It bombed with this web site's name.  SOE has little to do with a user id, a recursive algorithm can bomb when having to deal with too much data.

Answer (score 0):

0xe053534f is a StackOverflowException. You need to check if your setup script logic is resulting in any such stack overflow